# "error initializing submodules" when building from git in Docker Compose under GitLab CI

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, gitlab

I have recently changed an item in my `docker-compose.yml` to use a Git repo (via HTTP, not HTTPS or SSH) instead of a relative path, for use in GitLab CI.

This runs fine on my local machine and if I log in to the CI server as myself.

When it runs under GitLab, it gets to the `docker-compose build` step and exits with an error (shown here with `CI_DEBUG_TRACE` enabled and the `--verbose` flag on `docker-compose`):

```
$ docker-compose --verbose build
++ docker-compose --verbose build
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.auth.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/gitlab-runner/.docker/config.json', '/home/gitlab-runner/.dockercfg']
docker.auth.find_config_file: No config file found
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/version HTTP/1.1" 200 559
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
docker-py version: 2.6.1
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localunixsocket
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: KernelVersion=3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64, Components=[{u'Version': u'18.02.0-ce', u'Name': u'Engine', u'Details': {u'KernelVersion': u'3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64', u'Os': u'linux', u'BuildTime': u'2018-02-07T21:17:42.000000000+00:00', u'ApiVersion': u'1.36', u'MinAPIVersion': u'1.12', u'GitCommit': u'fc4de44', u'Arch': u'amd64', u'Experimental': u'false', u'GoVersion': u'go1.9.3'}}], Arch=amd64, BuildTime=2018-02-07T21:17:42.000000000+00:00, ApiVersion=1.36, Platform={u'Name': u''}, Version=18.02.0-ce, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=fc4de44, Os=linux, GoVersion=go1.9.3
compose.project.build: ldap uses an image, skipping
compose.service.build: Building cas
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (pull=False, labels=None, target=None, nocache=False, container_limits={u'memory': None}, cache_from=None, extra_hosts=None, network_mode=None, tag=u'<our project>_cas', buildargs={}, rm=True, stream=True, path='http://<our gitlab url>/gitlab/docker/rubycas-server-docker.git', dockerfile=None, forcerm=False, shmsize=None)
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Looking for auth config
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: No auth config in memory - loading from filesystem
docker.auth.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/gitlab-runner/.docker/config.json', '/home/gitlab-runner/.dockercfg']
docker.auth.find_config_file: No config file found
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: No auth config found
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.25/build?q=False&pull=False&remote=http%3A%2F%2F<our gitlab url>%2Fgitlab%2Fdocker%2Frubycas-server-docker.git&t=<our project>_cas&nocache=False&forcerm=False&rm=True HTTP/1.1" 500 802
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build -> <generator object _stream_helper at 0x7fb49ebb1eb0>
compose.cli.errors.log_api_error: error initializing submodules: usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] [--] <path>...
   or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [-f|--force] [--rebase] [--reference <repository>] [--merge] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
   or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
   or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
: exit status 1
```

I've followed the [GitLab documentation on submodules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/git_submodules.html) and had no luck.

To my knowledge, there aren't even any submodules in the project being built from git.

If it's helpful, here is the problem service from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
cas:
  build:
    context: http://<our gitlab url>/gitlab/docker/rubycas-server-docker.git
  depends_on:
    - "ldap"
  networks:
    - test-net
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

and the Dockerfile of the project being pulled from git (the submodule lines were added while I was troubleshooting, and don't seem to have helped):

```
FROM ruby:2.1.5

# Repo dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install git sqlite3

# Code
RUN git clone https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-server.git /rubycas-server/
COPY config.yml /rubycas-server/

WORKDIR /rubycas-server/

# Pull submodules
RUN git submodule sync --recursive && git submodule update --init --recursive

# Need to downgrade to Ruby 2.1.5 but latest rack-test requires 2.2.2
RUN sed -i 's/"rack-test"/"rack-test", "~> 0\.7\.0"/' rubycas-server.gemspec

# Ruby dependencies (include database adapter)
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install && bundle add sqlite3

# Create the database file and log - they're empty
RUN sqlite3 cas.db ''
# RUN touch cas.log

CMD bundle exec rubycas-server -c config.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

**Actual solution**

The server was using a very old version of git. Upgrading the git package manually to the most recent solved the issue and allowed me to use the latest `docker-ce` version.

---

<strike>This seems to be an issue with the latest edge version of `docker-ce`. I downgraded from `18.02.0.ce-1.el7.centos` to `17.12.1.ce-1.el7.centos` by disabling the `docker-ce-edge` repo and reinstalling, and the problem is resolved.</strike>

Comment: The solution worked for me after i uninstalled the old git and updated the git. You can use the link -- https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2021/12/installing-git-2-on-centos-7/ for that.